# Can't print a string on the console

Tags: java, printf

I can't figure out why I'm getting errors in the console when I compile this simple program, which should just print a string (2 separate files):

```
/*WordCount.java*/
//for the map
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
public class WordCount{ 
    private String stringToTest;
    //Map<String,Integer> mp = new HashMap<String, Integer>();//declaring a map object
    //constructor
    public WordCount(){
        stringToTest = "This is the string I want to test, and I'm curious to see the results.";
    }//end of constructor   
    public String getString(){
        return stringToTest;
    }
    System.out.printf("%s ", getString());  
}//end of WordCount class


/*WordCountTest.java
    WordCountTest to test the class
*/

public class WordCountTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        WordCount wordCount = new WordCount();      
    }
}//end of WordCountTest
```

These are the errors I get:

```
G:\JAVA\GUI\2015\createFrames\word_counter\test>javac *.java
WordCount.java:19: error: <identifier> expected
        System.out.printf("%s", getString());
                         ^
WordCount.java:19: error: illegal start of type
        System.out.printf("%s", getString());
                          ^
WordCount.java:19: error: <identifier> expected
        System.out.printf("%s", getString());
                                         ^
WordCount.java:19: error: ';' expected
        System.out.printf("%s", getString());
                                          ^
WordCount.java:19: error: illegal start of type
        System.out.printf("%s", getString());
                                           ^
WordCount.java:19: error: <identifier> expected
        System.out.printf("%s", getString());
                                            ^
WordCount.java:19: error: ';' expected
        System.out.printf("%s", getString());
                                             ^
WordCount.java:21: error: reached end of file while parsing
}//end of WordCount class
 ^
8 errors
```

I'm just creating an object, the constructor assign the string to the variable and I print out that variable. Still I can't quite understand why this isn't compiling
Thanks

Comment: it might be because `System.out.printf` is randomly laying in the class without beeing in a method or the constructor...

Comment: @KevinEsche LMAO didnt see that :D

Answer (score 0):

the line `System.out.printf("%s", getString());` is causing an error because it is not in a method or constructor in your example. You can either put it in the constructor, if that is where you want it to be run:

```
public WordCount(){
    stringToTest = "This is the string I want to test, and I'm curious to see the results.";
    System.out.printf("%s", getString());
}
```

or in it's own method, e.g.:

```
public void printString() {
    System.out.printf("%s", getString());
}
```

Comment: that's OK,understood, thanks :-). But I'm pretty new to java, so I wonder, why is this the case? Is it part of the syntax, I mean is there a rule saying for instance, all System.out.print and all statements need to be inside a method? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because your print statement isn't contained within a method. Try something like the following

```
public class WordCount{ 
    private String stringToTest;
    //Map<String,Integer> mp = new HashMap<String, Integer>();//declaring a map object

    //constructor
    public WordCount(){
        stringToTest = "This is the string I want to test, and I'm curious to see the results.";
    }//end of constructor   

    public String getString(){
        return stringToTest;
    }

    public void printString() {
        System.out.printf("%s ", getString()); 
    } 
}//end of WordCount class
```

And then you can use it in the following way

```
public class WordCountTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){
         WordCount wordCount = new WordCount();     
         wordCount.printString(); 
    }
}//end of WordCountTest
```

Comment: Ah, thanks guys, sorry it never occurred to me that it had to be either inside a method or constructor. It works now (I added it to the constructor.) Is this specified anywhere (that a printf can't be outside a method or constructor?)